# ambiguity partial template specialization for member and member functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I don't understand why this code fails to compile in `main()` due to "ambiguous class template instantiation" when using `&T::b` and `&T::c`. Is it a bug of g++ 4.6.1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct T{
    int a;
    void b(){}
    int c()
    { 
        return 1; 
    }
};

template<typename CT, CT> struct member_helper;

template<typename FT, FT(T::*mem)> 
struct member_helper<FT(T::*), mem> {
    static string worker()
    { 
        return "for members"; 
    }
};

template<typename Return, typename... Args, Return(T::*fun)(Args...)> 
struct member_helper<Return(T::*)(Args...), fun> {
    static string worker()
    { 
        return "for member functions returning non void"; 
    }
};

template<typename... Args, void(T::*fun)(Args...)> 
struct member_helper<void(T::*)(Args...), fun> {
    static string worker()
    { 
        return "for member functions returning void"; 
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << member_helper<decltype(&T::a), &T::a>::worker();    //prints for members, ok
    cout << member_helper<decltype(&T::b), &T::b>::worker();    //cannot distinguish between all of the three
    cout << member_helper<decltype(&T::c), &T::c>::worker();    //cannot distinguish between member function returning non void and member
}
```

EDIT:

here's the full error message:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp" 
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
../main.cpp:27:45: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct member_helper’ 
../main.cpp:13:43: error: candidates are: struct member_helper 
../main.cpp:17:78: error: struct member_helper 
../main.cpp:21:59: error: struct member_helper 
../main.cpp:27:8: error: incomplete type ‘member_helper’ used in nested name specifier
../main.cpp:28:45: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for ‘struct member_helper’ 
../main.cpp:13:43: error: candidates are: struct member_helper 
../main.cpp:17:78: error: struct member_helper 
../main.cpp:28:8: error: incomplete type ‘member_helper’ used in nested name specifier make: * [main.o] Errore 1
```

and this is the copmiler version:

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++-4.6.real
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
>   Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
>   --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

Comment: (@Nawaz: T is a real type, the struct just above - really confusing though)

Comment: @Mat: Funny. He is working with templates, and has defined `T` as class, creating confusion, even though English Alphabet has 26 letters.

Comment: @Griwes: compiles with 4.5.3, but fails with 4.6.2 and 4.7.something

Comment: Besides a **full** error message (that will include *why* the compiler considers them ambiguous) you should include the compiler and version, as this is a tricky enough problem that the compiler might not be processing it correctly (I have the feeling that the different partial specializations have a complete order "returning void" more specialized than "returning non void" more specialized than "member", so it might be a compiler issue)

Comment: I'm trying to workaround this with enable_if in typedefs within the class bodies, and g++ 4.6.1 crashes!! But it seems to run fine wih 4.5.1: http://ideone.com/CbclS

Comment: I reported this bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52744
by the way with some innocent looking changes this code snippet can even crash g++. See the source attachments on the bug report for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a g++ [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52744) -- it was fixed in 4.8.x for those who run across this in the future.